flutter Unhandled Expection: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
This error is not about firebase. Both shared_preferences and path_provider packages will report this error. This exception only appears on Android devices (both emulators and real devices). When building on Windows11, everything is normal. This exception troubles me because it suddenly occurs when I upgrade to flutter 3.19.6 and flutter upgrade some packages. All my codes should be normal:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await ConfigService().initConfigurations();
  await DataStore().initDB();
  MediaKit.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

  Future<void> initConfigurations() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

 Future<void> initDB() async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
}

ERROR:
 [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

It will be so good if anyone has clues to solve this problem. It came suddenly and I can no longer dev on Android since.
I have tried flutter pub outdated, flutter pub upgrade outdated_package, flutter clean, flutter pub get then flutter run. Those just won't work.

Does this answer your question? Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

I have tried those solutions available on StackOverflow, none worked for me. I have also deletes and recreated android folder, and change flutter version. Still not work.

A temporary solution is changing minifyEnabled to false in your app-level gradle to solve the issue. Probably minifyEnabled: true with a proper proguard file is a more favor solution, I will try to update it
   buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
   release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }

}

2024 not working anymore

Double check your Android emulator to make sure it targets the same API level for your Flutter project.
I had the same issue when my emulator was targeting API level 30 and creating an emulator that target API level 33 or 34 fixed it.

If you are using native bridge and adding flutter module into native iOS code add this line where you are initialising flutter engine
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: flutterEngine!)
and
import FlutterPluginRegistrant
